# How to test Multiplatform SwiftUI app in Catalyst on a Mac

Tags: xcode, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I'm learning SwiftUI, and have a Multiplatform App I'm building. Selecting Multiplatform causes Xcode 15 to create both MacOS and iOS targets.

I would also like to test out my iOS app and make sure it works in Catalyst, since that would make that version useful for both platforms.

I don't see a way to test the iOS app on my Mac in Catalyst. It only lets me select the native Mac app as a Mac target. Is it possible, and if so, how? (Running Sonoma on the Mac, Xcode 15.1, and building an iOS 17 target.)

Answer (score 0):

The default project in Xcode 15 comes with

[image]

Where macOS is selected.

You have to change the target to Catalyst.

[image]

Notice at the top that the available Mac now says Catalyst.

If you want a macOS App and a Catalyst app you can add a separate target.

[image]

in Xcode 13 and 14 Apple would create a "Shared" folder where all the files within would be shared with all the targets.

[image]

When you want to swap between the MacOS and the iOS/Catalyst app you will have to switch the target.

[image]

But remember that a Catalyst app is for all intents and purposes an iOS app all the AppKit tools are not available you have to use UIKit.

Comment: How do you do that for a SwiftUI Multiplatform application, and without losing the Mac native target as well? (I want to build an iOS app that works on iOS devices and on Macs under Catalyst, and a native Mac app as well.)

Comment: It seems odd to build a SwiftUI app for Mac with Mac Catalyst. Why not build a native Mac app with the same SwiftUI code?